# Java: How can I refactor a method to a class and then use its parameters in other classes?

Tags: java

3 weeks of experience with Java here.
I have these two classes - AppTest and AppTest2 and I have the same code in both of them:

Here is my code:

```
public class Apptest/AppTest2 {
     public WebDriver driver;
     public WebDriverWait wait;

     @DataProvider(name = "dataProvider")
     public Object[][] setUp() throws Exception {
     File firefoxPath = new File(System.getProperty("lmportal.deploy.firefox.path", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"));
     FirefoxBinary ffox = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
     ffox.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":20");
     driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffox, null);
     wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds );
     Object[][] data = new Object[1][2];
     data[0][0] = driver;
     data[0][1] = wait;
     return data;
 }

  @Parameters({ "driver", "wait" })
  @Test(dataProvider = "dataProvider")
  public void twoUsersSignUp(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait) throws InterruptedException{

       //test here

     }
}
```

How can I take this code out (setUp()), make it a class and then pass those variables to the next void "twoUsersSignUp"

EDIT: Im not looking for automatic solution, I just want to refactor this, so I dont have the same code in both classes

EDIT2: After I implemented the accepted answer's solution, I now have a problem with passing the variable "driver" to the next method in the first class:

```
     @AfterClass
     public void quit () {
         driver.quit();
     }
```

How do I do that?

EDIT3: This is the @AfterClass solution:

```
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
     @Configuration 
     @AfterClass
     public static void quit (@Optional WebDriver driver) {
         driver.quit();
     }
```

EDIT4: actually EDIT3 doesnt work, it just hides the errors from Eclipse. I still can't access "driver" :(

EDIT5: I decided that I dont need to have it in an AfterClass TestNG annotation, so I removed all the unnecessary stuff and it now looks like this:

```
     public static void quit (WebDriver driver) {
         driver.quit();
     }
```

and the variable has been declared this way:

```
public static WebDriver driver;
```

but still it doesnt work

EDIT6: fixed this by actually calling the method in the test code. Beforehand I didnt have to call it, because testng.xml had it called, but after I removed the @AfterTest annotation, it had been excluded from there!

Comment: What do you mean by "convert a method to a class"?  They are two very different things; what's your motivation here?

Comment: Take what out? What do you need to pass? You cannot convert a class to a method.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  What do you mean by "How can I take it out as a class" ?

Comment: @JennyKowalski You cannot annotate a non-static method with `@AfterClass` - your `quit` method needs to be static. It wouldn't be able to access the `driver` variable, though, unless it is made `static` as well.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I made it this way    `@Parameters({ "driver" })
   @AfterClass
   public static void quit (@Optional WebDriver driver) {
    driver.quit();
   }` and I made the WebDriver static, but Im getting a nullpointerexception

Comment: @JennyKowalski The `@AfterClass` does not "understand" `@Parameters`, so no `driver` is not passed to it. The method has access to the `driver` of the `AbstractAppTest` class, though, so you can remove the parameter after making that variable static.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight fixed it by adding these before `@AfterClass:    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Configuration `

Comment: actually, I've just hidden the problem without solving it. at the end of the test, the firefox window wasnt closed, which means the method quit didnt work :(

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Edited again.

Comment: @JennyKowalski Did you try what I suggested above (removing the parameter and making the variable static)?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes I did, in the AppTestData class, I have declared it this way:  public static WebDriver driver;

Comment: @JennyKowalski I am not current on JUnit any longer (I worked in C# for the last 5+ years). You may want to post the follow-up as a separate question, abstracted down to a single class with the `setUp`, `twoUsersSignUp`, and `quit` methods, because the split into two classes is not essential to why the `quit` does not quit the driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert a method to a class, but you can move a method to a place from which it would be shared by both `Apptest` and `AppTest2`: create a base class, and make the `Apptest` and `AppTest2` classes *extend* it.

```
public abstract class AbstractAppTest {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;

    @DataProvider(name = "dataProvider")
    public Object[][] setUp() throws Exception {
        File firefoxPath = new File(System.getProperty("lmportal.deploy.firefox.path", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"));
        FirefoxBinary ffox = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
        ffox.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":20");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffox, null);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds );
        Object[][] data = new Object[1][2];
        data[0][0] = driver;
        data[0][1] = wait;
        twoUsersSignUp(data);
        return data;
    }
    public abstract void twoUsersSignUp(@Optional Object[][] data) throws InterruptedException; 
}
public class Apptest extends AbstractAppTest {
    public void twoUsersSignUp(@Optional Object[][] data) throws InterruptedException {
        ...
    }
}
public class AppTest2 extends AbstractAppTest {
    public void twoUsersSignUp(@Optional Object[][] data) throws InterruptedException {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now the code of the `setUp` method does not need to be repeated, and it uses the implementation of the `twoUsersSignUp` method provided in each of the two subclasses of `AbstractAppTest`.

Comment: Thank you! Another problem has occured, I've changed My question with an EDIT2 where I've described it. @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 1):

You can't just convert a method to a class.

However, you can create new objects or modify existing objects.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your testData class like this

```
public class ApptestData{
 public WebDriver driver;
 public WebDriverWait wait;

 public ApptestData() throws Exception {
 File firefoxPath = new File(System.getProperty("lmportal.deploy.firefox.path", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"));
 FirefoxBinary ffox = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
 ffox.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":20");
 driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffox, null);
 wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds );
 Object[][] data = new Object[1][2];
 data[0][0] = driver;
 data[0][1] = wait;
 twoUsersSignUp(data);
 return data;
 }
}
```

And then use that object in your test classes

```
    public class Apptest/AppTest2 {

     @Test
     public void twoUsersSignUp() throws InterruptedException{

       AppTestData data = new AppTestData();
       //test here

     }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The kind of refactoring you are looking for [does not exists yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387914/can-eclipse-convert-refactor-a-method-to-a-class), at least on Eclipse.

A workaround to do it manually [is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1806865/1654265)

By the way, in Eclipse by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> you will find all the current available possibilities to refactor your existent code, by extracting methods, classes etc.